# Can I use WhereEqualTo two time in the same field?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to sort data in BUCKET_1_KEY field by two data, but it's not working in my case. Is it possible?

```
db.collection(XPERT_MASTER_KEY)
                .document(xpertId)
                .collection(RESPONSES_KEY)
                .whereEqualTo(BUCKET_1_KEY, "exp")
                .whereEqualTo(BUCKET_1_KEY, "option")
```

[image]

Comment: ask me anything related to the topic thanks.

Comment: do u want to sort data on 2 fields or filter data on these 2 fields?

Comment: Edited, see the image link please you will understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conditions in Firestore queries are logically AND'd with each other.  Therefore, it doesn't make sense to have two equals conditions in a single query on the same field.  A field value cannot possibly be equal to two different strings at the same time.

If you are trying to implement a logical OR query, trying to get all documents where BUCKET_1_KEY is equal to "exp" **OR** BUCKET_1_KEY is equals to "options", you should be using a IN query instead.  Please [read the documentation about IN queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any).  If you are trying to perform a logical OR with an IN query, it would look like this:

```
db.collection(XPERT_MASTER_KEY)
                .document(xpertId)
                .collection(RESPONSES_KEY)
                .whereIn(BUCKET_1_KEY, Arrays.asList("exp", "option"))
```

Comment: there no whereField() method to implement,can i try out anything else

Comment: Sorry, I gave the answer for swift, not Java.  Edited.  Please always refer to the linked documentation for examples

Comment: thanks, I figured that out but, absence of any field my app crashing.

Comment: I'm actually not pashing hardcoded string, rather passing two-variable containing string value. but there are possibilities that one variable may not contain string all the time. can you help me with that? And by the way, your carrier path is inspiring